# Why does this code work with c++17, but don't work with c++20 (MSVC)?

Tags: c++, c++17, metaprogramming, constexpr, c++20

I have `constexpr_sequence` class that returns new value with each `next()` call and current value with `value()` call depending on function and start value given as template parameters. For example:

```
template<typename T, T INC>
constexpr T increase(T val)
{
    return val + INC;
}

using counter = qx::constexpr_sequence<struct Tag, int, 0, increase<int, 1>>;
static_assert(counter::value() == 0);
static_assert(counter::next()  == 1);
static_assert(counter::value() == 1);
static_assert(counter::value() == 1);
static_assert(counter::next()  == 2);
static_assert(counter::value() == 2);
static_assert(counter::next()  == 3);
static_assert(counter::value() == 3);
```

This code works fine with MSVC, Clang, Apple Clang and GCC and C++17, but tests for MSVC fails when I enable C++20 (`counter::value()` always returns 0, despite the fact that `counter::next()` DO modify corresconding flag.

Сlass code:

```
template <class Tag, typename T, T Start, T Func(T)>
class constexpr_sequence
{
private:

template <T nIndex>
struct Element
{
    static constexpr T value(void) noexcept
    {
        T _value = Start;

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nIndex; i++)
            _value = Func(_value);

        return _value;
    }
};

template<std::size_t nCurrent, bool bWasSetted /* = false */>
struct CheckerSetter
{
    static constexpr std::size_t index(void) noexcept
    {
        return nCurrent;
    }
};

template<T nCurrent>
struct CheckerWrapper
{
    template<bool        bWasSetted = constexpr_flag<Element<nCurrent>>{}.test(),
             std::size_t nNext      = CheckerSetter<nCurrent, bWasSetted>{}.index()>
    static constexpr std::size_t index(void) noexcept
    {
        return nNext;
    }
};

template<std::size_t nCurrent>
struct CheckerSetter<nCurrent, /* bool bWasSetted = */ true>
{
    template<std::size_t nNext = CheckerWrapper<nCurrent + 1>{}.index()>
    static constexpr std::size_t index(void) noexcept
    {
        return nNext;
    }
};

public:

template <std::size_t nIndex = CheckerWrapper<0>{}.index(),
          T           _value = Element<nIndex>{}.value()>
static constexpr T value(void) noexcept
{
    return _value;
}

template <std::size_t nIndex = CheckerWrapper<0>{}.index(),
          T           _value = Element<nIndex>{}.value(),
          bool        bStub  = constexpr_flag<Element<nIndex>>{}.test_and_set()>
static constexpr T next(void) noexcept
{
    return Func(_value);
}

};
```

Class have my `constexpr_flag` class as dependency, this class returns "Start" at the beginning(`test()`), "Start" with `test_and_set` and "End" after `test()`. Tests for this code pass successfully, but you can check it if you think the problem is here.

repo:
[constexpr_flag](https://github.com/n0lavar/qxLib/blob/master/include/qx/meta/constexpr_flag.h)
[constexpr_sequence](https://github.com/n0lavar/qxLib/blob/master/include/qx/meta/constexpr_sequence.h)
[test_constexpr_flag](https://github.com/n0lavar/qxLib/blob/master/tests/test_constexpr_flag.cpp)
[test_constexpr_sequence](https://github.com/n0lavar/qxLib/blob/master/tests/test_constexpr_sequence.cpp)

To reproduce the problem:

```
git clone https://github.com/n0lavar/qxLib.git
open qxLib\cmake\platform_options.cmake, change cxx_std_17 to cxx_std_20

git clone https://github.com/google/googletest.git
cd googletest
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
cd ..
cd ..

cd qxLib
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DGENERATE_TESTS=1 ..
cmake --build .
```

build will fail with `test_constexpr_sequence` (and dependent on them `test_constexpr_random` and `test_rtti`)

Questions:
Why doesn't this code work?
Is the MSVC behavior correct (it would be cool to see references to the standard)?
What changes do I need to make to fix it?

Comment: For me this `constexpr_sequence` is suspicious. How should it work if it is used in multiple translation units?

Comment: It was designed for class ids purposes, it worked just fine for me with c++17. Anyway, your question not about the real problem

Comment: *Why doesn't this code work? Is the MSVC behavior correct (it would be cool to see references to the standard)? What changes do I need to make to fix it?* -- Maybe the compiler is broken?  If the compiler exhibited this behavior, wouldn't the first place to go to would be the Microsoft site and show them your findings?  I'm sure the engineers there would get out a fix (if broken) as soon as possible.  If the compiler is broken, they would be the ones that could fix it -- no one here would be able to do that.

Comment: Makes sence, reported as possible compiler error https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1300886/possible-error-in-compiler-with-cpp20.html